# Select TOP 2 results in variables without loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, variables

I want to store the top 2 results in 2 variables.

```
create table t(id int);
insert into t (id) values (1),(2),(3),(4);
    
declare @id1 int
declare @id2 int

select top 2 @id1 = first id, 
             @id2 = next id
from t
```

### [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/89b4e/4)

Can I do it in one query without using a loop?

Comment: What version of sql server?

Comment: On second thought better sql-server 2008

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
declare @id1 int,@id2 int

;with cte as (
  select top (2) id
  from t
  order by id
)
select @id1 = min(id), @id2 = max(id)
from cte

select @id1,@id2
```

**[Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d95e6/6)**

Comment: +1 in this particular case this one is the best I think ;) If you need to order by another column this one will not work, though

Comment: @RomanPekar: do you mean something [like this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9ca75f/2)? It works for ordering second column as well. Or you mean something else?

Comment: @Kaf - here's an example - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/14a37/3, suppose you want rows ordered by val and get first and second id. Your solution gets min and max id instead of first and second. However, as I said, in OP particular case it's working ok

Answer (score 3):

```
with cte as (
    select top 2 id, row_number() over(order by id) as rn
    from t
    order by id
)
select
    @id1 = (select id from cte where rn = 1),
    @id2 = (select id from cte where rn = 2)
```

or

```
with cte as (
    select top 2 id, row_number() over(order by id) as rn
    from t
    order by id
)
select
    @id1 = max(case when rn = 1 then id end),
    @id2 = max(case when rn = 2 then id end)
from cte
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/89b4e/31)</kbd>**

Answer (score 2):

You can use `LEAD()` for SQL Server 2012.

```
SELECT TOP 1 @id1 = ID, @id2 = LEAD(ID) OVER (ORDER BY ID) FROM t
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/89b4e/19)

Answer (score 1):

With two SELECT it's easy...

```
DECLARE @id1 INT
DECLARE @id2 INT

SELECT TOP 1 @id1 = x.id 
    FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) RN FROM t) x 
WHERE x.RN = 1

SELECT TOP 1 @id2 = x.id 
    FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) RN FROM t) x 
WHERE x.RN = 2

SELECT @id1, @id2
```

With SQL 2012 you clearly could

```
SELECT @id1 = id 
    FROM t ORDER BY id OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY

SELECT @id2 = id 
    FROM t ORDER BY id OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
```

Or evein in 2008 you could

```
; WITH Base AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) RN FROM t   
)

SELECT @id1 = b1.id, @id2 = b2.id
    FROM Base b1, Base b2
    WHERE b1.RN = 1 AND B2.RN = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @id1 int
declare @id2 int

declare @table table(id int,rownum int)

insert into @table
select top 2 id,row_number() over( order by id) as rn from t

select @id1=case rownum when 1 then id else @id1 end,
@id2=case rownum when 2 then id end from @table

select @id1,@id2
```

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/96504/1)

Answer (score 0):

More easy way with 2 selects:

```
declare @id1 int
declare @id2 int
select top 1 @id1 = id from t
select top 2 @id2 = id from t
select @id1, @id2
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/89b4e/39)